# Starting a exe process in bat without starting a new CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a certain part of my script, I want to run a certain executable, but I can`t do exactly what I want:

- 1:

  `"path/to/my/file.exe"`

will execute the file perfectly, however, my batch will stop executing until file.exe ends, and that's not what I want.

- 2:

  - 2.1:

  `start "path/to/my/file.exe"`

  - 2.2

  `start "path/to/my/file.exe" /b`

2.1 will start another cmd window, which I don't want. 2.2 Won't allow my batch script to return, and we're back to 1.

- 3:

  `call "path/to/my/file.exe" /b`

Back to 1.

So, is there any way of doing what I want? Simply starting an executable and let it run in the background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you you want

```
start "" /b "path/to/my/file.exe"
```

?

Bill

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot, Bill.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to run this using WScript:

```
Set shell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
shell.Run "cmd /c path/to/my/file.exe", 0, false
```

Comment: Hmm, there's no other way to directly do it using batch? :/ I wanted to avoid adding yet another script to my already large number of required files, but if that's the only way, I'll do it.

Comment: i agree with Rajiv. Batch is antiquated. You could use powershell or WScript. Just dump that above into a .vbs file. To call the vbs file you do either cscript "name of vbs.vbs" or wscript "name of vbs.vbs". It's simple for what you need to do, and doesn't hold up rest of the script on the exe shell.